# How to do pandas rolling apply in numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to apply `pandas.rolling(window).apply(func)` paradigm to numpy arrays. While searching [came across this function for numpy](https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html). This is what I did with it.

```
def rolling_apply(fun, a, w):
    r = np.empty(a.shape)
    r.fill(np.nan)
    for i in range(w - 1, a.shape[0]):
        r[i] = fun(a[(i-w+1):i+1])
    return r

def test(x):
    return x.sum()

arr=np.random.rand(20)
e=rolling_apply(test,arr,10)
```

when running it gives this error

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Can you please tell me why this error is happening

EDIT:

This works I made an initial error in the above code. This is working

Comment: Why can't you apply your function to the whole array, then take a rolling slice to your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

There was a little mess with array shapes and indexing. Quick fix:

```
def rolling_apply(fun, a, w):
r = np.empty((a.shape[0]-w+1, w))
r.fill(np.nan)
for i in range(w - 1, a.shape[0]):
    r[i-w+1] = fun(a[(i-w+1):i+1])
return r

def test(x):
    return x*2

arr=np.random.rand(20)
e=rolling_apply(test,arr,10)
```

Comment: Your original code (and by that I mean the code after your edit, which came later than my answer) gives `nan`s in the beginning of the result array. Are you sure you want it that way? If not, change the `r` array declaration to `r = np.empty(a.shape[0]-w+1)` and `r`s row assignation to `r[i-w+1] = fun(a[(i-w+1):i+1])`.

Comment: yep thats what I am looking for it should roll over the numpy array and  compute. If you can come up with different way to do this then I can accept your answer.